# Books on Test of Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references

I need some good intuitive books on Test of Hypothesis.I am an undergraduate  student and I didn’t find any intuitive books on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The following books might help you

1. Hypothesis Testing: An Intuitive Guide for Making Data Driven Decisions by Jim Frost ISBN: 978-1735431154
2. Hypothesis Testing: A Visual Introduction To Statistical Significance ISBN:978-1973181460